# Highcharts over SSL on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, highcharts

This is my first post on stackoverflow, I've looked around and haven't found an answer to this one yet:

I've got highcharts in a gwt application running on gae.  Over http highcharts works fine, forcing https through setting security-constraint as CONFIDENTIAL in web.xml causes the application to be unable to render charts.

In main html page I am calling is 'script type="text/javascript" src="js/highstock.js">

Must the application allow unsecure resources in order to run highcharts then?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you would like to use highstock by SSL, you need to download file from our website and load locally.

Comment: What file would that be?  Highcharts.js, Highcharts-more.js are already loaded on the server as evidenced by the fact that it works under HTTP protocol.

Comment: Check also that [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#files-outside-domain).